# I was popular in the 1970s

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus, history

I was popular in the 1970s. I can be represented by the following image:

[image: Two images of Darth Vader on the left and right of a wide gap. There is a right-facing arrow to the right of the left Darth Vader and a left-facing arrow to the left of the right Darth Vader.]

What am I?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

That looks to me like

> a game of SPACE IN VADERS.

Comment: I hope this is it lol

Comment: In fact, they (Star Wars and the answer) were both popular in the late 1970s :)